# How to correctly implement conditional statements for more than just one comparison value per condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, lookup, sanitization

So I was **writing a weather app program which tells you based on your input what things u should do** but someone how the error is as shown in the image.kindly excuse me for such a question actually I am just a beginner so I needed a help! I thought for the Winter input it will show me Wear a cool Jacket but instead it should me Wear cap.I don't know whats's the issue kindly help.

[image: Error Which I am facing]

```
// Question:
// Write a weather app if Summer=>Wear Cap Winter=>Wear a cool Jacket Rainy=> Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella

// GuideLines
console.log("Welcome to the Weather app \n")
console.log("Kindly Tell What Kind of weather you are experiencing \n")
console.log("Type: Rainy or rainy if raining \n")
console.log("Type: Summer or summer if it is hot summer \n")
console.log("Type: Winter or winter if it is cool freezy winter \n")

// Taking Input
let weather = (prompt("What Kind of weather you are experiencing?"))

// Conditions

if(weather==="Summer" || "summer"){
  console.log("Wear Cap")
} else if(weather ==="Winter" || weather=="winter"){
  console.log("Wear a cool Jacket")
}else if (weather=== "Rainy" || "rainy"){
  console.log("Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella")
}else {
  console.log("Hmm! It seems an invalid input. Kindly read the Guidelines")
}
```

I thought for the Winter input it will show me Wear a cool Jacket but instead it should me Wear cap.
I don't know whats's the issue kindly help

Comment: `weather==="Summer" || "summer"` doesn’t do what you think it does. It’s equivalent to `(weather==="Summer") || "summer"`, and `"summer"` will always be true.

Comment: The code could be made both more robust and also simpler by lower casing and trimming the user input ... e.g.  ... `let weather = (prompt("What Kind of weather you are experiencing?")).toLowerCase().trim()` ... then the OP could compare just with the expected lower case season or weather  condition names like ... `if (weather === "summer") { ... }` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You made typos in your first and third if clauses. Because of that, it will always return true. Just change your code like this:

```
if(weather == "Summer" || weather == "summer"){
  console.log("Wear Cap")
} else if(weather == "Winter" || weather == "winter"){
  console.log("Wear a cool Jacket")
} else if (weather == "Rainy" || weather == "rainy"){
  console.log("Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella")
} else {
  console.log("Hmm! It seems an invalid input. Kindly read the Guidelines")
}
```

You can also write like this with switch/case:

```
switch (weather) {
    case "Summer":
    case "summer": {
        console.log("Wear Cap")
    }; break;
    case "Winter":
    case "winter": {
        console.log("Wear a cool Jacket")
    }; break;
    case "Rainy":
    case "rainy": {
        console.log("Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella")
    } break;
    default: {
        console.log("Hmm! It seems an invalid input. Kindly read the Guidelines")
    }; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code could be made both more robust and also simpler by [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)ming and [lower casing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) the prompted user input e.g. ...

```
// Taking Input
let currentWeather = prompt("What kind of weather you are experiencing?")
  .trim()         // - immediately sanitize the
  .toLowerCase(); //   prompted input value.
```

... then the OP could compare just with the expected lower case season or weather condition names like ...

```
if (weather === "summer") { /* ... */ }` // and so on.
```

But an even better approach was to use an object as lookup where one would map the outfit suggestions as value to any expected all lowercase weather key.

```js
// Question:
// Write a weather app if
//  - Summer => Wear a Cap.
//  - Winter => Wear a cool Jacket.
//  - Rainy  => Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella.

// GuideLines
console.log("Welcome to the Weather app.");
console.log("Kindly tell what kind of weather you are experiencing.");
console.log("Type: Rainy or rainy if raining.");
console.log("Type: Summer or summer if it is hot summer.");
console.log("Type: Winter or winter if it is cool freezy winter.");

// Conditions
let outfitSuggestions = {
  summer: "Wear a Cap.",
  winter: "Wear a cool Jacket.",
  rainy: "Oh! You need to carry an Umbrella.",
}
let suggestionDefault =
  "Hmm! It seems an invalid input. Kindly read the Guidelines.";

// Taking Input
let currentWeather = prompt("What kind of weather you are experiencing?")
  .trim()         // - immediately sanitize the
  .toLowerCase(); //   prompted input value.

console.log(outfitSuggestions[currentWeather] || suggestionDefault);
```

Comment: @PradyotSinha ... the OP might check on the above provided late answer.